# No route matches [GET] "/sessions/2" for a delete request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, logout

I'm trying to add a log out link on the admin side but it seems to be doing a get request even though I specifically specified it as a delete request.

NOTE: BTW I'm not using Devise and I'm intentionally not using it for this project.

```
<%= link_to session_path(current_user), method: :delete do %>
   <%= fa_icon "sign-out" %>
   Logout
<% end %>
```

This is the code I'm using on the admin nav bar. It's also the same code as the one used on the front end of the website but the code on the the front end works. It successfully logs the user out. But on the admin side it raises that error.

This is what's used on the front end of the website and it works.

```
<%= link_to "log out", session_path(current_user), method: :delete %>
```

This is what's in my route file:

```
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

and this is the path format:

```
session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                sessions#destroy
```

This is the destroy method:

```
def destroy
  cookies.delete(:auth_token)
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
end
```

Can anyone see what the problem is with logging out from the admin side?

NOTE: BTW I'm not using Devise and I'm intentionally not using it for this project.

EDIT 1: 
OK So I'm thinking "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery" this is causing the error. I have Jquery required before Bootstrap so I don't know what's going on here.

Comment: Two questions: 
1) Do you include jquery-ujs in your JavaScripts? 2) Are there any errors in your JS console?

Comment: Yes I do have jquery-ujs in the admin_application.js file and there are no errors in the js console

Comment: what is fa_icon in block?

Comment: Oh that's font-awesome. It just shows an icon. I've taken that code out and tried it as a single link_to line and it still raises the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:i, "Sign Out", :class => "fa fa-#{icon_name}"), session_path(current_user), method: :delete %>
```

OR

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:i, fa_icon("sign-out", text: "Sign Out")), session_path(current_user), method: :delete %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still raises the error. I'm thinking it's a JS problem but I can't see anywhere where the problem lies with JS

Comment: Just realised I have this error "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery" and it's causing certain JS elements to not work. For example, I have data-confirm message on a link but it doesn't fire. Am pretty sure that this is causing the problem.

Comment: OK so I found the problem =) I forgot to include the javascript tag which includes jquery in my admin_application.html.erb file.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem. I forgot the include 
`<%= javascript_include_tag 'admin_application' %>` 
in my admin_application.html.erb file which meant that jquery was not included. Now that it is, the log out link works. Yay!